# Is there a bug in the sysinfo(2) man page?

Tags: linux

The manpage (also) documents struct sysinfo.
The size of this struct differs on 32 and 64 bit systems.
(Because the struct is made of longs).

You can read these comments in the manpage:

```
...
/* Pads structure to 64 bytes */
...
/* Padding to 64 bytes */
...
```

But this is not completely right. On 64 bit the size of the struct is 112 and not 64.
So I think this is a bug?

Comment: The second comment is wrong. But the size is correct -- in all cases it is `sizeof (struct sysinfo)`. In fact, the size is probably architecture- or compiler-dependent -- it depends on the padding strategy after the `short` field. I am also *fairly* certain "Number of current processes" should not be constrained to be < 65536 for much longer.

Comment: "Use the source, Luke." `/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h` in this case, but the types `long`, `int`, and `short` are conspicuous by their absence.

Comment: It may or may not be a bug : The standard gives only the minimums of the sizes of int, long and short ; the hardware architecture & the OS & the compiler decide on the exact sizes & paddings & alignments. Taking short = 2 bytes && int = 2 bytes or 4 bytes && long = 4 bytes , we get struct sysinfo = 64 bytes with padding. I am using https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html to calculate that. You can confirm this on a 64-bit system by checking the sizeof(struct sysinfo) in a test C Program.

Comment: @Prem on Linux, `sizeof(int) == 4` in all cases, and `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)`, 4 bytes on platforms with 32-bit pointers, 8 bytes on platforms with 64-bit pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man page is definitely inaccurate, even in its historical presentation.

As you mention, on 32-bit platforms the `struct` ends up with a size of 64 bytes, as documented, but on 64-bit platforms it ends up with a size of 112 bytes (because longs are 8 bytes in length there, and the `struct` members end up aligned on 8 byte intervals).

As far as history goes, *before* 2.3.16, the `struct` was declared as follows:

```c
struct sysinfo {
    long uptime;             /* Seconds since boot */
    unsigned long loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    unsigned long totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
    unsigned long freeram;   /* Available memory size */
    unsigned long sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    unsigned long bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    unsigned long totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    unsigned long freeswap;  /* Swap space still available */
    unsigned short procs;    /* Number of current processes */
    char _f[22];             /* Pads structure to 64 bytes */
};
```

In 2.3.16, two fields were added (`totalbig` and `freebig`), and the padding was *removed*:

```c
struct sysinfo {
    long uptime;             /* Seconds since boot */
    unsigned long loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    unsigned long totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
    unsigned long freeram;   /* Available memory size */
    unsigned long sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    unsigned long bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    unsigned long totalbig;  /* Total big memory size */
    unsigned long freebig;   /* Available big memory size */
    unsigned long totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    unsigned long freeswap;  /* Swap space still available */
    unsigned short procs;    /* Number of current processes */
};
```

In 2.3.17, the new fields were moved to the end (someone presumably realised that the 2.3.16 change broke the userspace ABI), and padding was re-introduced, because of `libc5` (but with no overall size indication):

```c
struct sysinfo {
    long uptime;                /* Seconds since boot */
    unsigned long loads[3];     /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    unsigned long totalram;     /* Total usable main memory size */
    unsigned long freeram;      /* Available memory size */
    unsigned long sharedram;    /* Amount of shared memory */
    unsigned long bufferram;    /* Memory used by buffers */
    unsigned long totalswap;    /* Total swap space size */
    unsigned long freeswap;     /* Swap space still available */
    unsigned short procs;       /* Number of current processes */
    unsigned long totalbig;     /* Total big memory size */
    unsigned long freebig;      /* Available big memory size */
    char _f[22-2*sizeof(long)]; /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
};
```

2.3.18 changed the padding to `char _f[20-2*sizeof(long)];`, to account for the padding between `procs` and `totalbig`.

2.3.23 renamed `totalbig` and `freebig` to `totalhigh` and `freehigh`, and added `mem_unit` (adjusting the padding accordingly), leaving pretty much the structure [as it is today](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/sysinfo.h); since then, some explicit padding has been added for Motorola 68k, and the types have been changed to ensure that the appropriate type for the kernel is used regardless of the “standard” type definitions:

```c
struct sysinfo {
    __kernel_long_t uptime;     /* Seconds since boot */
    __kernel_ulong_t loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freeram;   /* Available memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    __kernel_ulong_t bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freeswap;  /* swap space still available */
    __u16 procs;            /* Number of current processes */
    __u16 pad;          /* Explicit padding for m68k */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalhigh; /* Total high memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freehigh;  /* Available high memory size */
    __u32 mem_unit;         /* Memory unit size in bytes */
    char _f[20-2*sizeof(__kernel_ulong_t)-sizeof(__u32)];   /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
};
```

I haven’t found any sign of a separate `/* Padding to 64 bytes */` line in the kernel history. That appears to have been introduced by a man page contributor, replacing “Padding for libc5” with “Padding to 64 bytes” in release 3.41 of the man-pages project, perhaps based on the same comment in the `libc5` copy of the header used for example in Debian.

I’ll submit a patch, unless you want to take care of it!

Comment: +1 for Detailed Answer !! I am curious to know : (1) Why was it necessary to make it 64 bytes ? In 64-bit systems, it exceeds 64 bytes and is not even 128 bytes; The "calculated" padding seems "un-useful" because nothing broke with 112 byte struct. (2) Regarding new fields totalbig & freebig breaking the ABI, hence moving to end of struct : The change in memory values in terms of bytes and then in terms of mem_unit bytes is also a breakage in ABI ; Was that not a concern ?

Comment: (1) I don’t know, I haven’t found anything yet in libc5 that explicitly relies on the `_f` field or the size of the `struct`. (2) The breakage is somewhat different — adding fields in the middle means that programs which haven’t been recompiled will get mixed up values; changing the scale of the memory sizes still gives proportionate values, and in any case programs which aren’t aware of `mem_unit` can’t be given accurate values anyway. See [the comment here](https://github.com/schwabe/davej-history/blob/master/kernel/info.c).

Comment: Thanks for checking that ! Clarifying my "calculated" padding comments (3) Here `char _f[20-2*sizeof -sizeof ....];` , all old fields are taken into account by Magic Number 20, and only new entries are subtracted via `sizeof` which eventually crosses 64 bytes in 64-bit ; If it had been `char _f[64 - sizeof - sizeof ....];` this bug would have been caught earlier on 64-bit compilation where array size was negative. (4) I was wondering that the extra padding is harmless and/or unnecessary and hence a simple "uncalculated" padding `char _f[PAD=22];` should be enough to satisfy "libc5" et al.

Comment: Indeed. Amusingly enough, on 64-bit platforms the current definition leads to `_f` containing exactly 0 entries (but occupying 4 bytes in the `struct`). One more entry would break the build.